# How to fix the " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException " in my code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I created a jdbc connectivity project that i wanted to transfer from my laptop to another. 
I successfully transferred the mysql databases but on transferring the java file i get the error

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at PRO.initComponents(**PRO.java:80**)
at PRO.<init>(**PRO.java:8**)
at PRO$3.run(**PRO.java:156**)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)

on clicking (**PRO.java:8**) It takes me to the code

```
       jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/PIC/STORY13.jpg"))); // NOI18N
```

on clicking (**PRO.java:8**) It takes me to the code

```
        public PRO() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//
}
```

on clicking (**PRO.java:156**) It takes me to the code

```
       public void run() {
            new PRO().setVisible(true);
        }
```

PS: the whole jdbc project works on my laptop perfectly. But on doing the transferring again , the same error pops up.

Comment: I would start by looking what the PRO class in line 80. And I would rename the class to have a meaningful name. And I would not expect that anybody could help me with a code problem without showing code (see [mcve]).

Comment: @GhostCat i have done what you said.. you can scroll down . Please do tell me what is wrong! i have to submit my project next week.

Comment: You already got an answer: most likely, `getClass().getResource("/PIC/STORY13.jpg")` returns NULL, leading to NPE. so: that resource lookup fails on that other platform. Exactly like the answer you got 13 days ago suggests. Beyond that, honestly: you come back after 13, and now you are in a hurry? The help center explicitly states that people should be around when asking questions. It isn't exactly polite to drop a question, and to then walk away for multiple days. Hint: if your priorities are that tight ... then follow them up on time, and not 5 minutes before the assignment is due.

Answer (score 2):

This is not due to any jdbc problem, this is because it's looking for some image you used in your project that is missing from the machine you transferred to.